# Identify compression method used on blob/binary data

Tags: blob, compression

I have some binary data (blobs) from a database, and I need to know what compression method was used on them to decompress them.

How do I determine what method of compression that has been used?

Comment: It's not clear whether the "database files" are the files for the "mssql database that somebody else has made" or the database *itself* stores files (that are compressed) as BLOBs. The fact that you mention BLOBs implies the latter, but ...

Comment: There is a proprietary program that stores the files(images, pdfs, etc) into the database as blobs.

Comment: Scrap the stuff in your question that is totally irrepevant. PHP, SQL, BLOB - youiwould have exactly (!) the same problem if the binary data would live in files on the disc and you used C#.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is easier. Assume one of the standard methods was used, there possibly are some magic bytes at the beginning. I suggest taiking the hex values of the first 3-4 bytes and asking google.
It makes no sense to develop your own compressions, so... unless the case was special, or the programmer stupid, he used one of the well known compression methods. YOu could also take libraires of the most popular ones and just try what they say.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, in general, would be to store which compression method was used when you store the BLOB.

Comment: So there is no way to reverse-engineer the compression?

Comment: I don't think it's even possible, generally let alone practically, to reverse engineer the compression method even if you had both the compressed and un-compressed file. There are probably circumstances where this would be possible, but it's in essence a form of cryptanalysis, so it's more of an art than algorithmic.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the blob in db you can do the following:

1. Store in file

For my use case I used [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) to export multiple blobs to separate files.

2. Find out more about the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) from the file by doing

```
file -i filename
```

In my case the files are `application/zlib; charset=binary`.